# SonarQube configuration using Ant for Jacoco code coverage

Tags: ant, jacoco, sonarqube-4.5

- SonarQube version: 4.5.1
- Sonar Ant task: 2.2

We have configured the sonar build using ANT; Currently we are facing below errors,

1. > WARN: Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to
   >   include debug information into compiled classes
2. > WARN: File '/aa/bb/cc/abc.xml' is ignored. It is not located in the
   >   module base dir '/a/b/c/d'
3. > Java byte code scan   WARN: class '/a/b/c/d/e/f' is not accessible
   >   through classLoader
4. > [jacoco:report] classes in bundle 'project123'do not match with
   >   execution data. For report generation the same class files must be
   >   used at runtime
5. > [jacoco:report] Execution data for class 'com/tttt/xyz/aaa12' does
   >   not match
6. > [jacoco:report] To enable source code annotation class files for
   >   bundle 'project123' have to be compiled with debug information

Note:

1. All classes are compiled including debug information i.e. `<javac debug="true" />`

Our objective is to

1. Generate JaCoCo report
2. Display it on SonarQube dashboard (assume, Unit test coverage widget will display the coverage information?)

Not sure about the issue, hence need expert assistance.